# What is the best way to detect if media file isn't accessible (403/404s) with js/html player?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Trying to use .onerror [error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/error_event) will trigger only about a 80% rate for me.  On my demo page, doesn't matter if it's a refresh, force refresh or URL entry, try a few times and it will not detect the failed load.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mubhcaeb78/pen/NWyKoxM) of all code, with errant ID from google drive.  If you replace a valid one like: *1Cguauee-7MKN2nrXM_ZvdYRLEBglCvFG* it will play.

Excerpt with just specific parts:

HTML

```
<audio id="audioFile" src="URI"></audio>
```

Script

```
const audio = document.getElementById('audioFile');
audio.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log("Error " + audio.error.code + ": " + audio.error.message);
};
```

Is this .onerror the best route to go to make sure the media player doesn't hang waiting for a missing/rejected file?  With google drive being the source, I do see some 403 errors randomly popping up, that when refreshed a few times later dissipate.  I need to convey to reload when this occurs.

The browser always shows the error in dev console.   Instead do I do a fetch()?

Comment: Could you provide a working sandbox of the example on which you are basing your question?

Comment: In the codepen, this is likely an issue of the HTML element already having been interpreted, before your JS code to add the error handler even runs. Getting a 404 response from Google probably happened quite quickly, and binding your handler only _after_ that happened, will not trigger it retroactively. When I modify your code to only set the `src` of the audio element after the event handler was added, it appears to work pretty reliably (for me, in a Chromium based browser.)

Comment: @CBroe You are onto it.  Because the script is a module, it will always be deferred.
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) **"The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by default."**

I do not know if this is still the best method but this is what I did.
Create a script outside the module:

`<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = ("<p>File not found.</p>");
}, true);
</script>`

Thanks!